# Add RobotFramework to Ubuntu:16.04

Tags: python, robotframework, ubuntu-16.04

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qbunf.png)I want to download robotframework in ubuntu for dockerfile but i didn't found. What can i do?

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04
RUN apt-get update    
RUN apt-get install software-properties-common -y
RUN add-apt-repository --yes ppa:ansible/ansible-2.10 
RUN apt-get install ansible -y
RUN add-apt-repository -y ppa:jblgf0/python
RUN apt-get update 
RUN apt-get install python3.6 -y
RUN apt-get install python-requests -y
RUN apt-get install python-pip -y
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install robotframework
RUN pip install --upgrade robotframework-sshlibrary
ENTRYPOINT [/bin/bash]
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qbunf.png)

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04? Back then some of the python scripts were still in Latin. I'd recommend using a version that is a bit newer.

Comment: Please don't post pictures of errors. Take the time to copy, paste, and format the stacktrace directly in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are having problems with the versions you are requesting. `pip` for example is failing to install. Also `python3.6` is an old version.
You should update your Dockerfile to use Ubuntu LTS, which is currently in version 22.0.4.